# Most efficient way to extract all the (natural) numbers from a string

Tags: java, string, numbers, extract

Users may want to delimit numbers as they want.

What is the most efficient (or a simple standard function) to extract all the (natural) numbers from a string?

Comment: Note that "natural numbers" is ambiguously defined (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Also, is there any maximum limit on the size of numbers you want to allow, or can they be of any size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. I modified this example from  [Sun's regex matcher tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test {

    private static final String REGEX = "\\d+";
    private static final String INPUT = "dog dog 1342 dog doggie 2321 dogg";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
       Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); // get a matcher object
       while(m.find()) {
           System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
           System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
       }
    }
}
```

It finds the start and end indexes of each number. Numbers starting with 0 are allowed with the regular expression `\d+`, but you could easily change that if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly.  But if all you want is to pull out all non-negative integers then this should work pretty nicely:

```
String foo = "12,34,56.0567 junk 6745 some - stuff tab tab 789";
String[] nums = foo.split("\\D+");

// nums = ["12", "34", "56", "0567", "6745", "789"]
```

and then parse out the strings as ints (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the delimiter, then:

```
String X = "12,34,56";
String[] y = X.split(","); // d=delimiter
int[] z = new int[y.length];
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++ )
{
    z[i] = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(y[i]).intValue();
}
```

If you don't, you probably need to pre-process - you could do `x.replace("[A-Za-z]", " ");` and replace all characters with spaces and use space as the delimiter.

Hope that helps - I don't think there is a built-in function.