# How to Insert Commas Into a Number WITHIN a String of Other Words

Tags: java, string, insert, numbers, divide

I have a `String` like the following:

```
"The answer is 1000"
```

I want to insert commas into the number 1000 without destroying the rest of the `String`.

NOTE: I also want to use this for other `String`s of differing lengths, so `substring(int index)` would not be advised for getting the number.

The best way that I can think of is to use a `regex` command, but I have no idea how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give us more information. Is it always going to be 1000? Or is it a 4 digit number? Or can it be a longer number? Is it commas for every thousandth? (This is for future reference when asking questions... give unambiguous information so we can answer you)

Comment: with only one number in the phrase?

Comment: use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558432/extracting-a-number-from-a-string-in-java ?

Comment: where in the number should the comma go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following formats all the non-decimal numbers:

```
public String formatNumbers(String input) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();        
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while(m.find()) {
    String g = m.group();
    m.appendReplacement(sb, nf.format(Double.parseDouble(g)));            
  }
  return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

e.g. if you call: `formatNumbers("The answer is 1000 1000000")`

Result is: `"The answer is 1,000 1,000,000"`

See: [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This only works if there IS a number in the `String`. In a few cases, there will NOT be a number. When this happens, nothing appears on the screen. EX: I want "The answer is 1000". It says "The answer is 1,000" YAY! Now I want "That is a good answer". It says "" NO! Please help.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: For that just check if the `result` is empty or null. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice solution, never noticed `Matcher.appendReplacement()` before, very neat!  Too bad it uses `StringBuffer` :(

Comment: Is the output locale dependent? I get the pattern as 1,00,00,000

Answer (score 1):

modified from [Most efficient way to extract all the (natural) numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169437/most-efficient-way-to-extract-all-the-natural-numbers-from-a-string):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Example {

private static final String REGEX = "\\d+";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "dog dog 1342 dog doggie 2321 dogg";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input); // get a matcher object
    int end = 0;
    String result = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        result = result + input.substring(end, m.start());
        result = result
                + addCommas(
                        input.substring(
                                m.start(), m.end()));
        end = m.end();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static String addCommas(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.length() % 3 == i % 3)
            result += ",";

        result += c[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: As with βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ's post, this DOES NOT work for `Strings` that do NOT have numbers in them ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression:

```
[0-9]+
```

To find contiguous sets of digits, so it would match `1000`, or `7500` or `22387234`, etc.. You can test this on http://regexpal.com/ This doesn't handle the case of numbers that involve decimal points, BTW.

This isn't a complete, with code answer, but the basic algorithm is as follows:

- You use that pattern to find the index(es) of the match(es) within the string (the index of the characters where the various matches start)
- From each of those indexes, you copy the digits into a temporary string that contains **only** the digits of the number(s) in the String
- You write a function that starts at the end of the String, and for every 3rd digit (from the end) you insert a comma before it, unless the index of the current character is `0` (which will prevent `300` from being turned into `,300`
- Replace the original number in the source string with the comma'ed String, using the [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method